# Kafka Stream for Kafka to HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Flink Job which reads data from Kafka topics and writes it to HDFS. There are some problems with checkpoints, for example after stopping Flink Job some files stay in pending mode and other problems with checkpoints which write to HDFS too.
I want to try Kafka Streams for the same type of pipeline Kafka to HDFS. I found the next problem - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/365
Could you tell me please how to resolve it?
Could you tell me where Kafka Streams keep files for recovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Streams only interacts between topics of the same cluster, not with external systems.

**Kafka Connect** HDFS2 connector maintains offsets in an internal offsets topic. Older versions of it maintained offsets in the filenames and used a write-ahead log to ensure file delivery